# Depth first scan of a tree backwards

Tags: trees

How can I traverse this tree, to get a sequence of vertices `{8,4,2,9,5,1,6,3,7}`? I've failed to produce it with `DepthFirstScan`, does this particular order even has a name?

```
TreeGraph[{1->2,1->3,2->4,2->5,3->6,3->7,4->8,5->9}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Comment: Which algorithm did you use to produce this order or the vertices?

Comment: You can get pretty close using `DepthFirstScan` and the `"PostvisitVertex"` event - are you sure that's not what you want? Your order seems a bit strange, given that e.g. 2 is visited between visiting the two subbranches

Comment: @A.G. I don't know what's the algorithm is called, but it outputs the vertices while backtracking backwards from DFS.

Comment: @swish As I understand a vertex is listed when the DFS has exhausted its adjacency list. If that is correct, node "1" should be last in the list. Is that correct?

Comment: i am sure this is not what you want, but it does give `{8,4,2,9,5,1,6,3,7}`: `rubeGoldbergSort[g_] := 
 SortBy[VertexList[g], {PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] &}];  rubeGoldbergSort@
 TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 
   5 -> 9}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`:)

Comment: @kglr Suprisingly it also gives the right answer for a bigger tree graph I have, so it probably not a coincidence and this sort function is indeed traverses the tree the way I want it to, thx :)

Comment: swish, but this depends only on the layout. I was assuming the sequence was generated by something more subtle.

Comment: @kglr I'm also unaware of the original method, outputing vertices on backward motion of DFS was just a guess. But coordinate sort on default layout is apparently does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on swish's comment (*"Suprisingly it also gives the right answer for a bigger tree graph I have, so it probably is not a coincidence and this sort function is indeed traverses the tree the way I want it to"*), perhaps:

```
coordinateSort[g_] := SortBy[VertexList[g], PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates]&]; 

coordinateSort@TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 9}]
```

> {8, 4, 2, 9, 5, 1, 6, 3, 7}

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the following gets you close:

```
g = TreeGraph[{1->2,1->3,2->4,2->5,3->6,3->7,4->8,5->9}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]

Reap[DepthFirstScan[g, 1, {"PostvisitVertex" -> Sow}]][[2, 1]]
(* {8, 4, 9, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 1} *)
```

The difference between this and your order is that a vertex is only visited after *all* subbranches have been visited. (whereas your order lists them after the first subbranch, which seems a bit arbitrary)